# Vim: paste custom multi-line content in visual block

Tags: vim

I'm writing a Vimscript and I have a following problem with visual block paste. Let's say I have a file:

```
    eee
    eee
```

In visual block mode I select square region 2x2 starting on the first character.
I want to achieve result file

```
    abe
    cde
```

Programatically I set the unnamed register: `:let @@ = "ab\ncd"` and then I do `gvp`. Instead of the desired result, I get:

```
    ab
    cde
    e
```

I tried to set the register also as `"ab\<cr>cd"` but it produces output:

```
    ab^Mcde
    ab^Mcde
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't work without changing the type of your register:

```
:call setreg("c", "ab\ncd", "b")
```

See `:help setreg()`.

Note that I've used register `c` because `@` is not a valid register name.